"Never been used but twice"
What is this sentence wording called never been used but twice. Please explain this in depth to me
I'm trying to break this sentence down. Would you describe it as an oxymoron or paradox? Is there anything grammatically wrong with it?
[Someone online] tested my intelligence but in a very unclever way. He sounded very stupid but me having to prove a point engaged in his illiterate reply. I wrote, "it has never been used but twice." He responds, "What does that mean?" I say, "well, the first part is just our good ol southern language and the second part states it has only been used twice" he then says, please don't mistake good ol southern language with that post" or something like. So, I want to explain what kind of sentence this is and why or why not it works or is true.
Yes, it contradicts itself [editor: because if something has never been used it cannot have been used twice]. And yes, it was unintentional. Would the word but mean except in this sentence? How would you describe this?

I hurriedly used this sentence in a brief description of an item. It stuck a heated debate with some random man who pretty much called me an idiot. To me it was unintentional and most would have never even paid attention to it knowing what I truly meant but I want to break this down for him

Welcome: please add details with the question's Edit link. Most of all, add the meaning of what you intended your sentence to convey.

Hello and thanks for your responses. I am just wanted other views on this hot debate that some random man on Facebook started. In which it is very dumb and makes him appear to be an idiot.

However, I have entertained like another idiot lol. I am a writer and very fluent and sharp with the English language but I make mistakes just like all human beings do.

Sorry but the title sentence "Never been used but twice what" is meaningless to me. Please stay away from pejorative terms such as "idiots".

I do enjoy studying English and learning, especially hearing others thoughts, philosophies, ideas on it. It intrigues me! Anyway, I have to be "gramatically correct" enough in my life so usually if it is "unimportant " I take short cuts or pay little attention to detail or how I use my words.

With that being said, this man tested my intelligence but in a very unclever way. He sounded very stupid but me having to prove a point engaged in his illiterate reply. I wrote,  " it has never been used but twice." He responds, "what does that mean?" I say, "well, the first part is just our good ol southern language and the second part states it has only been used twice" he then says, please don't mistake good ol southern language with that post" or something like . So, I want to explain what kind of sentence this is and why or why not it works or is true

Please take the time to add explanatory detail to the question itself. This space isn't a chat room.

I'm trying to break this sentence down.  Would you descrine it as an oxymoron or paradox? Is there anything at all wrong with it? Yes, it contradicts itself and yes, it was an unintentional. Would the word but mean except in this sentence? How would you describe this?

Sorry a stranger wrote unkind things. Being anonymous brings out the worst in Jan Doe.

As pointed out before: please [edit] your post to add the information you gave in the comments. As it stands, it's unclear what you're asking from your question.

I've edited your post but if you feel the edit does more harm than good, you can rollback or modify it to your standard.

'Never been used but twice' is OK, but rather old fashioned English, meaning 'only used twice'. It's a bit 'dialect' - where do you live? 'But' here has the meaning 'except'.

But meaning ‘except’
But means ‘except’ when it is used after words such as all,
everything/nothing, everyone/no one, everybody/nobody: …

But (Cambridge Dictionary)
I would add 'never' to that list.

Thank you see the above comments for my explanation of this. I guess I'm trying to break this all the way down. Is it oxymoron or paradox? Is but meaning except and does that make the sentence true or whatever I'm sure you understand what i am saying

I am from Alabama lol

It's only an oxymoron to the very literal. Most would accept that it is almost new.

In southern American English it is not uncommon to find multiple negatives used  emphatically (rather than logically):

I ain't got no money. I ain't never had no money.

The speaker is a pauper and has been a pauper all their life.
So "never been used but twice" means "it has seen very little use, almost no use at all".
Compare:

I never saw it but once, and that was in the dark. It might have had pointy ears, I couldn't really say.

I saw it only once and that was just a glimpse in the dark.
It's not a paradox or an oxymoron, just relying on the negative "never" for emphasis, here emphasis that it is like new, that calling it "used" is hardly fair.

Short answer - don't use it, it sounds wrong in modern English.
You've had an answer telling you that 'but' can mean 'except' which is true, but it can also mean "only" or "just". This means that it could be used in two similarly constructed sentences to do the exact opposite - to introduce an exception to an absolute negative (for example, "nothing but trouble" or "nobody but me") or to positively affirm that the subject is an example of something (for example "there are but two rules" or "I am but a man"). All of these are somewhat archaic constructions (we would say "only" or "just" in modern English) but they still work as dramatic or extremely formal language.
It is often the case in English that idioms survive in their original form a lot longer than the form of English language they came from - for example, people still say "woe is me" from early modern English, for dramatic effect. The examples I used above of "nothing but trouble" and "nobody but me" are fairly commonly used, but there's something unusual and archaic about your example of "never but twice". If it isn't a recognised idiom that we've heard in its original form then it has to stand up to modern English grammar, and it just doesn't, probably because "never" is the most absolute adverb there is, meaning not once in the past, nor in the future. To have an exception to never just sounds a bit off. You'd be far better saying "only used twice".
